# How Join two list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I want have created Wikipage on my subsite in SharePoint 2013 online, I want to add two dependent dropdowns on my website... for that I have created two lists in my SharePoint subsite. How to link one List to another list... Just like SQL table PK-FK relationship.

List 1:

[image]

List 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join two lists:

Create lookup column refer to category list.

[image]

For Cascade Dropdown, you could use [SPCascadeDropdowns](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/wiki/SPCascadeDropdowns).

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/

For inner join query(need lookup column).

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/789d7f23-12ae-4454-a37b-e69580c9284d/caml-inner-join-in-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not quite clear about what you are saying -  may be you may handle this through the lookup column mapping between two lists.... in SharePoint list relationship is maintained by lookup column/list.

And if you are looking for connected list view webparts in SharePoint online you may go through the below article :

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/18/connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint-online/